# Simplify boolean expression, so close but yet so far

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

> $$F(w,x,y,z) = w'y' + w'z + x' + yz + y'z'$$

The simplest form is apparently $w'y' + x' + yz + y'z'$, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how, no matter what trick I use.

Comment: If w' and z are true, then one of w'y' or yz will be true in the second.

Comment: Consensus theorems applied to $w'y'$ and $yz$.

Comment: @Eugenebaba do you know Karnaugh's maps? This tool gives as result $w'y' + x' + yz + y'z'$ or alternatively $w'z + x' + yz + y'z'.$

Comment: @frabala it *is* true.

Comment: @frabala so I invite you to delete your comments and I will delete the mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Given $$F(w,x,y,z) = w'y' + \color{red}{w'z} + x' + yz + y'z',\quad\quad (*)$$ we want to show that $F(w,x,y,z)$ reduces to  $\;w'y' +  x' + yz + y'z'.$

For this, it suffices to prove that $\color{red}{w'z}$ is covered by other terms in $(*).$
Rewrite
 $$\color{red}{w'z}=w'zxy+w'zx'y+w'zxy'+w'zx'y'.$$ 
Note that $w'zxy$ is covered by $yz,$ and similarly find in $(*)$ a covering term  for each of $w'zx'y,\; w'zxy',\; w'zx'y'.$

Answer (score 1):

The $yz+y'z'$ terms take care of all cases where $y$ and $z$ have *the same* truth value, so the other terms only matter if $y$ and $z$ have *different* truth values. In that case we have $z=y'$, so $w'y'=w'z$ and you only need one of those equivalent (in context) terms.